# Do degrees from the ETH of Zurich value the same as 'normal degrees'?

Tags: degree

I have noticed that the ETHZ gives the following degrees / titles upon graduating:

> Bsc ETH [Subject] instead of BSc [Subject].
>
> Msc ETH [Subject] instead of MSc [Subject].
>
> Dr. sc. ETH Zurich instead of Ph.D [Subject].

I am aware that there already is a question on academia stackexchange about why this is the case.

More interesting is the question about their equivalence in industry or academia. Please don't misunderstand. I don't want to ask if they have the same value as an Ivy-League degree or not. If a college or university asked for people having a master's degree or a Ph.D. degree, are candidates with a Msc ETH or Dr. sc. ETH considered too? Would they think something like 'Oh hey, he has a Bsc **ETH**, so he has no real bachelor.', or do they think that Bsc ETH = Bsc?

Comment: My impression ( I live on the Swiss border, and several people from my department have collaborated with people from the ETH) is that the ETH has good standing. If we were hiring and someone from the ETH came by, then that would not be held against her or him.

Comment: *I don't want to ask if they have the same value as an Ivy-League degree or not.* If you did, we would have told you that they do.

Comment: You know Einstein studied there, right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> are candidates with a Msc ETH or Dr. sc. ETH considered too?

Of course, yes.

The reason for the presence of the ETH qualifier is well explained in [this answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/63541/20058), and the (possible legal) validity of a certain degree can be established regardless of any qualifier attached to the degree.

Moreover, if you look at the position of [ETH Zurich](https://www.ethz.ch/en/the-eth-zurich/portrait/rankings.html) in international rankings, you will see that it can be certainly classified among the top universities. Whatever one can say about the real validity of such rankings, a university would probably not be able to stand in top positions if its graduates were systematically ignored in other university selections. And if this were the case just for the presence of the ETH qualifier, I'm sure they would have already removed it.

> do they think that Bsc ETH = Bsc?

Given the prestige of the ETH Zurich, I'm sure that several if not many selection committees would think Bsc ETH > Bsc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is.
The reason why ETH issue degree like MSc ETH rather than just MSc is that, in Switzerland, there is degrees like BSc FH or MSc FH (FH = Fachhochschule = University of Applied Science) which issued by the Universities of Applied Sciences and ETH wants to make difference (aka. show superiority)